# Delphi TRestClient SSL Handshake Error

Tags: delphi, ssl, indy, delphi-xe6

I am trying to consume a REST service on Amazon with Delphi XE6. At design time I add TRestClient, TRestRequest, TRestResponse components and set BaseURL property. When I execute the request, I get the following error:

```
While trying to execute the request the following error occured: REST request failed: Error connecting with SSL.
error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

Tried searching google, there were some suggestions to update Indy libraries, but something went horribly wrong and I had to spent some hours uninstalling everything Delphi related and reinstall.

So, it would be much appreciated if someone could guide me to right direction about how to resolve this error.

Maybe I can bypass TRest* components and use Indy components directly but I am not very experienced about which Indy components I would need.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: REST is just XML/JSON over HTTP.  You can use Indy's `TIdHTTP` component for that, and `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` for the SSL/TLS portion.  However, you are getting an OpenSSL error message to begin with, so switching to Indy may not solve your problem. The more likely culprit is an SSL/TLS configuration mismatch between what your REST client has enabled and what the REST server is expecting. Hard to say for sure without seeing the content of the sslv3 alert and the actual SSL/TLS handshake.

Comment: Server in question is on Amazon. I have tried TIdHTTP and executed .Head with every SSL configuration possible. I always get Handshake failure. What can I do to further investigate SSL/TLS handshake detail?

Comment: you can use Wireshark to analyze the handshake packets to see what the handshake is doing. The handshake itself is not encrypted.

Comment: Not a real answer, so I will post as comment. On weekend I have tried C# System.Net.Http and today I have tried Java jersey. Both have no trouble with SSL handshake. I went ahead with Java. Thanks @RemyLebeau for your help.